# Find files and print only their parent directories

Tags: linux, shell, command

I have the following commands.  Wherever the `.user.log` file is present, we need to print the parent directories (i.e `hht` and `wee1`.)  How can this be done?

```
$ cd /nfs//office/ && find . -name '.user.log'
./hht/info/.user.log
./wee1/info/.user.log
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Am I missing something here. Surely all this regex and/or looping is not necessary, a one-liner will do the job. Also "for foo in $()" solutions will fail when there are spaces in the path names.

Just use dirname twice with xargs, to get parent's parent...

```
# make test case
mkdir -p /nfs/office/hht/info
mkdir -p /nfs/office/wee1/info
touch /nfs/office/hht/info/.user.log
touch /nfs/office/wee1/info/.user.log

# parent's parent approach
cd /nfs//office/ && find . -name '.user.log' | xargs -I{} dirname {} | xargs -I{} dirname {}

# alternative, have find print parent directory, so dirname only needed once...
cd /nfs//office/ && find . -name ".user.log" -printf "%h\n"  | xargs -I{} dirname {}
```

Produces

```
./hht
./wee1
```

Comment: And can i do ll to find the permsissions of the resulting directory find . -name '.user_repo.log' | xargs -i{} dirname {} | xargs -i{} dirname {} |xargs ll

Comment: Assuming the ll you refer to is the commonly used alias for "ls -lA", then no. xargs will only run commands, not aliases. However, you could do "xargs ls -lA" instead...

Comment: Be warned, `-i` flag for `xargs` is listed as deprecated, preferably use `-I` flag instead.

Answer (score 13):

You can do this easily with the formatting options of the `-printf` action of `find` (see `man find`).

```
cd /nfs//office/ && find . -name '.user.log' -printf "%h\n"
./hht/info
./wee1/info
```

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

[image: Screenshot of find manpage]

`%h\n` will print path for each file on a new line.

Please note that `-printf` is GNU-only. It won't work on macOS (a BSD system).

Answer (score 3):

```
for file in $(find /nfs/office -name .user.log -print)
do
    parent=$(dirname $(dirname $file))
    echo $parent
done
```

EDIT: Sorry missed that you want the grandparent directory.

Answer (score 1):

@trojanfoe has the right idea; [this](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh) is just a way to get it to work safely with *any* filename, and pretty much any command within the loop:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    echo "$(dirname -- "$(dirname -- "$REPLY")")"
done 9< <( find "/nfs/office/" -name '.user.log' -print0 )
```

If you want it to echo only the *unique* names:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    echo "$(dirname -- "$(dirname -- "$REPLY")")"
done 9< <( find "/nfs/office/" -name '.user.log' -print0 ) | sort -u
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a different file descriptor?

Comment: In case you want to do something with stdin inside the loop. It's explained at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
cd /nfs/office/ && find . -name '.user.log' | xargs -n1 -I{} expr match {} '\(\.\(\/[^/]*\/\)\?\)'
```

where the `xargs` uses `expr match` to extract the part that starts with `.` until the first match of directory between slash characters (`/dir/`).

An alternative version using `sed` would be as follows:

```
cd /nfs/office/ &&  find . -name 'file.txt' | sed -r 's|(\./([^/]*/)?).*|\1|'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "${1%/*}"' bash {} \;
```

Comment: Can you give a bit of explanation of this? I can confirm it works, but I'm particularly confused by the `1%` and the final `bash {}`

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(find . -name ".user.log" -exec readlink -f {} \;)
do 
     parent=$(dirname $i)
     echo $parent
done
```

this may work and produces output like

/nfs/office/hht/info

/nfs/office/wee1/info

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a one-liner using `awk`. This is useful if you don’t have access to `printf` (eg. on macOS) or wish to have greater and more easily parsable control over which parts of the path you wish to extract.

`find . -iregex ".*.user.log" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS="/"} {$NF=""; print $0}' | uniq`

- The [`find`](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Find.html) command with a proper [regex](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html) will already find what you’re looking for.
- [`awk`](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) then creates fields for each `find` result using `/` as field separator `FS` (and replacing them afterwards with `OFS`) and prints the entire line (`print $0`) except for the final field (`$NF=“"`) which is the filename you may not want to see (eg. `.user.log`).
- [`uniq`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) simply ensures you don’t get multiple copies of the same path if several copies of the file pattern appear in a single directory.

If you don’t want the entire paths but only parts thereof, change `print $0` to `print $4` for example.

Answer (score -1):

```
find /nfs/office -name '.user.log' | while read line
do
    echo $line | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1),$NF}'
done
```