# Find files and print only partial-parent-folder+filename

Tags: bash, find

This question is really similar to what I am looking for.
[Find files and print only their parent directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597433/find-files-and-print-only-their-parent-directories)

I don't want to print the fullpath, rather half of it and the file itself.

Example:

```
/disk1/data/foo-1/xx.csv
/disk1/data/foo7/yy.csv
/disk1/data/bar-2/zz.csv
/disk1/data/bar9/nn.csv
```

and I want to print as follows:

```
foo-1/xx.csv
foo7/yy.csv
bar-2/zz.csv
bar9/nn.csv
```

I'm currently using this code:

```
find ${base_folder} -type f -mmin +2 -name "*.csv" -print | rev | cut -d"/" -f1-2 | rev > ${LIST}
```

Which is working and for months it worked 100% of the time.

I wonder if there is a better/prettier way of writing the same code.

Comment: And what is the problem? You just want a "prettier" version?

Comment: Are you guaranteed GNU `find`? What's the value of `base_folder`?

Comment: BTW, `find ${base_folder}` behaves completely identically to `find $base_folder` -- both will split the name `base_folder` contains on whitespace and expand each word created by that splitting process as a glob. If you want to avoid that behavior, quote the expansion: `find "$base_folder"` or `find "${base_folder}"`

Comment: @PesaThe yes exactly, a prettier version than `rev` - found (:

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for suggestion! I have many files, some are really long, and I want to avoid the space problem in the file name. I believed both `"$var"` and `${var}` were the same but with `${var}` being used in this context: `"the word is: ${var}"`

Comment: @Nihvel, they're both perfectly safe in a quoted context, *except* when you want to suffix the expansion with characters that might otherwise be seen as part of the variable name. So, for instance, `echo "The word is $var"` is fine, but `echo "Your change is ${cents}c"` needs the curly braces so it doesn't try to expand `$centsc`. Either way, though, you need double quotes; curly braces without them don't suppress string-splitting or glob expansion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy gorgeous! thanks!! and yes, i forgot, `$base_folder ` is /disk1/data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find -printf` with `%P` to avoid including `base_folder` in the output:

```
find "$base_folder" -type f -mmin +2 -name "*.csv" -printf '%P\n'
```

Comment: I like this solution! I was trying to do some weird stuff with `sed` but I'm not that skilled in regex. Tested and working! Thanks sir!!